# Typescript type definition vs inference

Tags: typescript

In the below example:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAKAlMgfFAbnASwBMBuAKABsJgoBDALlgSgB8oBXAOyIgDMDOEIsg7c+AoeTIBjOJwDONaSIzYoAbzorMSHLIVwqAOgpwA5qgBEACQIBCS5gC+5aRikFeaWpnVkoAXTuZE5AA)

```
type Foo = () => void;
let a: Foo | undefined = undefined;

const c = () => { a = () => console.log("Hi!") };
c();

if (a) {
  a();
}
```

At line 4 the type of `a` is `let a: Foo | undefined` but at line 8 it is `let a: never`.
Therefore `tsc` shows this error: `Type 'never' has no call signatures` at line 8.

But it doesn't if line 2 is `let a: Foo | undefined;` (removed the variable assignment)

I guess it will be something related with Type Inference. The [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) states that:

> In TypeScript, there are several places where type inference is used
> to provide type information when there is no explicit type annotation.
>
> ```
> let x = 3;
>     ^
>     let x: number
> ```

But I this example there is an explicit type annotation.

I understand that TS cannot know if the function `c` will be executed and, therefore, that `a` will be assigned. That is why I have put the explicit definition of the type of `a` in its declaration.

So why is the type defined for `a` not respected at line 8?

Comment: Fixed your corrupted playground link. Interestingly, if you don't assign to `a` (so it's implicitly `undefined`), it works. Looks like a bug to me and the side-effect of `c` assigning to `a` isn't picked up.,It does, however, highlight the merits of pure functions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unsound behaviour, as you note in your question. The behaviour is noted in an open issue on the GitHub issue tracker, titled [Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998):

> **Optimistic: Bad behavior on locals**
>
> The TypeScript compiler has code like this:
>
> ```
> enum Token { Alpha, Beta, Gamma }
> let token = Token.Alpha;
> function nextToken() {
>     token = Token.Beta;
> }
> function maybeNextToken() {
>     if (... something ...) {
>         nextToken();
>     }
> }
>
> function doSomething() {
>     if (token !== Token.Alpha) {
>         maybeNextToken();
>     }
>     // is this possible?
>     if (token === Token.Alpha) {
>         // something happens
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Optimistically assuming `token` isn't modified by `maybeNextToken` incorrectly flags `token === Token.Alpha` as an impossibility. However, in other cases, this is a good check to do! See later examples.

The problem is that making the compiler more pessimistic would be detrimental in other cases, because the compiler would fail to detect real bugs in your code. As of writing this answer, the issue is over 5 years old and still open, and it looks like the language designers haven't agreed on whether anything needs to be done about it, or if so what.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the issue, I was unaware of the optimistic vs. pessimistic behavior. Interesting reading. Apart from that, if in the example I completely delete the `c` function, the same still happens. If I don't assign `a = undefined` the error doesn't appear. Is there any explanation for that? Or is it just a corner case?

Comment: If you delete the `c` function and the call to it, then the behaviour is correct; `a` is undefined where you declare it, and then you test `if(a)` which cannot be true at that point in the code, so `a`'s type is narrowed to `never`. That's [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

Comment: Yes, I agree. But if line 2 is `let a: Foo | undefined` instead of `let a: Foo | undefined = undefined` then `a` is still `undefined` but `tsc` shows no error. That's the question. That's what I find strange. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAKAlMgfFAbnASwBMBuAKABsJgoBDALlgSgB8oBXAOyIgDMDOEUmTIFeaWpgDeZKHQzkAviKA)

Comment: Because if you don't assign it as `undefined` then it isn't known to be `undefined` at that point in the code, so its type isn't narrowed to `undefined`. When you write `let a: Foo | undefined` you're saying that `a` could be either `Foo` or `undefined`. When you write `let a: Foo | undefined = undefined` you're saying that `a` is `undefined` now but might be `Foo` later. Your `if` test is now instead of later, so `a` can't be `Foo`.

Comment: Oh! Okay. I just confused narrowing with inference. Thank you very much!